# Looking for TV Series or Movie about AI taking over the earth, probably aired in the 90's

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a TV series or most likely a movie about a robot AI taking over the earth. I watched it when I was a kid on TV, in the US, so it probably aired during the 90s. I'm fairly certain it was a movie. I remember the AI robots being big spherical objects, with blue horizontal lights for eyes. When they were about to attack, it would switch to red.

The main hero of the story was a man, had dark hair and lived in the slums(?). The robots lay waste to the slums and all of the power goes out.I remember a distinct scene about five or so men hiding in a cupboard in the dark. They talked to each other about having to live in there. I remember this scene distinctly, because as a child I thought, how on earth could they fit in there?

The other main heroine of the story was some sort of news reporter, and went up to the higher class of buildings, where everyone was living peacefully, to stop the attack on the slums. The higher class people were controlling the robots somehow.

I don't know if I ever saw the end, so maybe they end up winning somehow. I would really love to find out what this was. Some elements may have been taken from other movies, I would've been really young at the time, so if it doesn't meet these exact specifications, that would be okay. I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Movies I'm sure that **it isn't**:

- *I, Robot*
- *The Matrix*
- *War of the Worlds*

Comment: Was the movie animated or live-action? Did the robots have legs with spherical bodies, or did they roll/fly with no legs?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. They were flying spherical objects, and it was definitely live action.

Comment: [This](https://www.zdnet.com/pictures/15-of-the-best-movies-about-ai-ranked/) might serve useful, but just ignore the more recent movies; i.e., if you *still* haven't figured out what TV series or movie it was :)

Comment: @user477343, Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @user477343, Metropolis (1927) looks really promising, (maybe the movie was black and white?) Thanks for the help. I'll have to check it out to make sure though.

Comment: No problemo. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 4):

This may be a long shot, but there was a movie released in 1970 titled Colossus : The Forbin Project. It is about a super computer that enslaves the world. It has control of the worlds nuclear arsenal. During the course of the movie, attempts to subdue it are defeated.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to check the movie out, but it sounds like it might be it.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know: Did you ever get a chance to check out *Colossus*?